# Update React configuration across components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I store config settings, set by the client, in local storage.  When somebody updates a value, we save it to local storage.  When they load the page, we grab it from local storage.  The code for a sticky state is:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function useStickyState(key, defaultValue) {
    if (!process.browser) {
        return React.useState({})
    }

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(() => {
        const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        return stickyValue !== null
            ? JSON.parse(stickyValue)
            : defaultValue;
    });
    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);
    return [value, setValue];
}
```

Using this,  I can make a settings system pretty easily:

```
import useStickyState from "./useStickyState";

export default function useSettings() {
    const [config, setConfig] = useStickyState('config', {
        shortLength: 4,
        password: '',
        expirationTime: 0,
        focus: 'usability'
    })

    return [config, setConfig]
}
```

Then, I can access settings using:

```
    const [config, setConfig] = useSettings()
```

However.  I have multiple components that use these settings.  When one of them calls `setConfig()`, I want them all to update.  Is this possible?  How would one go about doing this?

The only method I can think of at the moment is polling every x seconds, which seems an awful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html): load the settings from a parent component and pass them down to children using a Context Provider and the useContext hook.

I created [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-forked-5zsgg?file=/src/index.js) that updates the config from the child and causes the parent and other children to re-render.